# findViewById returns null on inside views of include

Tags: android, android-layout, include

I have similar problem like this thread [findViewById returns null on a LinearLayout inside an <include>d view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454206/findviewbyid-returns-null-on-a-linearlayout-inside-an-included-view/)

I have similar problem:

xml that calls the include block:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            ...>
    <include  
                android:id="@+id/popupMenu"
                layout="@layout/mainmenu_popup" /> 
    </RelativeLayout>
```

and mainmenu_popup.xml that contains the included code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/action_bar_height"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
      <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainmenupopup_fragment"
        class="RetailMobile.MainMenuFragment" />
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/mainmenupopup_fragment" 
            android:background="@color/dark_blue"
            android:id="@+id/blueLine" />
    <RelativeLayout
        ...
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I follow Luksprog's answer

```
RelativeLayout popupMenu = this.Activity.FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.popupMenu);
```

**but popupMenu == null**

i also checked this thread [findViewById not working for an include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803672/findviewbyid-not-working-for-an-include) with no positive result.

Comment: What view are you trying to get?

Comment: In what activity life cycle event you call findViewById? If you call it before you set the contentView for activity, then it would fail.

Comment: I try to access it from OnCreateView method of a Fragment, after Inflate on its layout(the one with <include>).

Answer (score 2):

add `android:id` to RelativeLayout in mainmenu_popup.xml and then find view by id defined there

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution
mainmenu_popup.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popup_mainmenu">
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/popup_mainmenu_inner"> ...
```

then i refer to popup_mainmenu_inner:

```
 this.Activity.FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.popup_mainmenu_inner);
```

Comment: not so happy so far because i found that if my parent container is Fragment(where i `call FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.popup_mainmenu_inner)`) it is still null, only works if parent container is FragmentActivity or Activity